# Git, Bitbucket, Eclipse and a new project

Tags: git

I want to add my project to the remote Git repository.
I am using Bitbucket to manage Git.
Eclipse as IDE to create my project.

So I have cloned the repository locally using Eclipse.

How can i add/commit this new project to Git remote branch?

Comment: You have to commit on local branches and then push them into the remote.

Comment: thanks. I did not know I had to do 'Add Index' before committing. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

> I did not know I had to do 'Add Index' before committing

This is describe (with [EGit: Git on Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)) as ["Add to Version Control"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Commit)

[image: Add to version control]

> You can see for example in the Package Explorer View which files have been added (file icon marked with "`+`") and which files have been modified (file marked with "`>`" in front of the filename).

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/8/8b/EGit_AddedAndModifiedFiles.png]

*Then* you can commit:

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/b/b9/EGit_CommitDialog.png]